# Calculate row total

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to show a row total to go along with grand total but I'm not sure how. I did find the grand total by doing a union all and having it be all nulls except the total column. Not sure how to find just by the parent though. Thanks.

```
select parent
,location
,total
from test

union all

select null as parent
,null as location
,sum(total) as total
from test
```

[image]

Comment: Have you have a look at `ROLLUP` and `GROUPING_SETS`?

Answer (score 0):

Using two `GROUPING SETS` you can do this:

```
SELECT parent, location, sum(total) as total
FROM test
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((parent, location), ());
```

A row with the total will be generated for each `GROUPING SET`. One row for each distinct `(parent, location)` combination and a single row containing the total of all rows `()`.